# Converting (a) an entity-relationship diagram about an airline booking scenario to (b) a relational schema

Tags: database-design, erd

I am currently following notes on a certain "7 step strategy" to transform an ERD to a relational schema and was wondering some points about step 4, converting one-to-many (1:N) relationships.

The relevant ERD is the following one:

[image: ER Diagram]

**Questions**

1. Would `SEAT` contain

   - `Seat_no`, `Date` (from `LEG_INSTANCE`)

   or

   - `Seat_no`, `Customer_name` (from `RESERVATION`), `Cphone` (from `RESERVATION`), `Date` (from `LEG_INSTANCE`)?
2. Would `FLIGHT_LEG` contain `Scheduled_dep_time` & `Scheduled_arr_time`?

Comment: All I can say from having worked in the industry is that flight_leg must contain a scheduled_dep and scheduled_arr which are both datetimes. There should also be blocks_off and blocks_off and other VR details.

Answer (score 2):

First, a 1-N relationship, the table on the N side would have the key of the table on the 1 side configured as Foreign Key.

So depending how leg_instance is keyed, either:

```
  Seat: seat_no, Date(from leg_instance), leg_no (from flight_leg), Number (from flight), 
  with key (Number,leg_no,seat_no)
  and foreign key (leg_no,Date) => leg_instance(leg_no,Date)
```

or

```
Seat: seat_no, leg_instance_id (from leg_instance)
with key (leg_instance_id, seat_no)
and foreign key (leg_instance_id) => leg_instance(leg_instance_id)
```

Then, the table on the N side caries all attributes of the relationship, so here Seat would also have Customer_name and Cphone.  It would be permissible to introduce a separate table for Reservation that is 1-1 with Seat, but 1-1 relationships are normally just merged into a single table.  That table might end up being named SEAT, RESERVATION or something like SEAT_RESERVATION, as it implements the ERD shapes with both those names.

> Another question I have is would flight_leg contain scheduled_dep_time & scheduled arr_time ?

You should be able to answer that yourself, now.